# How to make circular background using css?

Tags: css

I need make something like this. and I want to do it for a `<div></div>` which has `width` in `%`

[image]

I can do this by using an image and adding another `div` inside and `z-index`.

But I want to know if it's possible to make in this circle in backgroud using css.

Answer (score 110):

**Keep it simple**:

```
.circle
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px; 
}
```

Width and height can be anything, as long as they're equal

Comment: אהלן, thanks for your answer, how do I include a number right in the center of the circle?

Answer (score 46):

Check with following css. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dyBY8/)**

```
.circle { 
   width: 140px;
   height: 140px;
   background: red; 
   -moz-border-radius: 70px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
   border-radius: 70px;
}
```

For more shapes you can follow following urls:

http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles

Comment: css3shapes.com redirects to scummy website

Comment: border-radius of 50% is is sexier

Answer (score 28):

Use circular gradient for background property

```css
div {
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #f73134 0%,#ff0000 47%,#ff0000 47%,#23bc2b 47%,#23bc2b 48%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

PS: Fiddle is down (404)...

Answer (score 16):

It can be done using the `border-radius` property. basically, you need to set the border-radius to exactly half of the height and width to get a circle.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FNdXz/151/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container
{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    border:1px black solid;
}

#inner
{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background:black;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-top:25%;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks but I'm asking to achieve this using a single `div` if it's possible

Comment: but if that is not possible in your solution I will have to use z-index because I need to add some text and images overlaping the circle

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty smart solution, @xbonez.

Comment: @JitendraVyas: The only way to achieve that without using an inner div would be by using an image. As a sidenote, you can overlay text. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/FNdXz/1/

Comment: I suppose you'd be best off using a svg image as background, in that case

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes to put a multi-layered background on a element.

```
#divID : before {
    background: url(someImage);
}

#div : after {
    background : url(someotherImage) -10% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: you can do it by this way too: #div{background:url(someimage), url(someotherImage)}

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://bryanhadaway.com/how-to-create-circles-with-css/) is a solution for doing it with a single `div` element with CSS properties, `border-radius` does the magic.

CSS:

```
.circle{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#000
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="circle">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a display inline-block too:

```
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with only 1 element, you can use the ::before and ::after pseudo elements for the same div instead of a wrapper.
See http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/