# How to cut a part of div

Tags: css

I try to give you a broad picture of my problem. Suppose I have a overlay `div` on my page with `z-index: 99;`, with `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`. Then I want to remove a part of overlay `div`, for example `100 x 100px` in `top: 50px;` and `left: 200px;`.

By removing I mean that exclude a part of overlay `div` to make that part visible and remove the `background-color` from that.

How can I do that?

Comment: I guess it comes to masking of certain part of `<div>` and clone it with same element (or background) so it appears to be clipped. Bet you can get the idea from Flipboard inspired project http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/ with demo here (http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/?page=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can remove part of the background like you describe. Instead, your overlay can have a transparent background and it can contain four blue-ish-background `div`s that form a frame around the hole you want.

Here's some code that does this:

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
#main {width: 500px; height: 200px; background: yellow;}
.overlay {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position:absolute;}
#overlay-container { width: 500px; height: 200px; z-index: 99; position: absolute;}
#top {width: 100%; height: 50px}
#left {top:50px; width: 200px; height: 100px}
#right {left: 300px; width: 200px; height: 100px}
#bottom {left: -300px; top: 100px; width: 500px; height: 50px}
```

```html
<div id="main"/>
<div id="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay" id="top"/>
    <div class="overlay" id="left"/>
    <div class="overlay" id="right"/>
    <div class="overlay" id="bottom"/>
</div>
```

You can probably get rid of the `overlay-container` and simplify things a bit.

For the overlay, you could just use a `<div>` with a transparent background and a translucent border. Here's another example:

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#background {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background: yellow;
}
#overlay {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 50px;
    border-left-width: 200px;
    border-right-width: 200px;
    border-bottom-width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="background">some content</div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What about the circles?

Comment: @MuhammadOsama -- What circles? If you want a circular background, you can probably do some tricks using the `border-radius` property. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8709291/535871).

Comment: @TedHopp is there any way to create the same thing with border radius?!

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani - As I said in my comment just above yours, you can probably play around with the `border-radius` property. See the question I linked to in the comment.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, thanks. actually, I was looking for the first example. so one question: as you know, pointer-events: none will make it clickable from the inside, but I need to somehow also prevent from clicking underlying items from outside, is there any way to do that? (consider it as a walkthrough tour for website which user should only able to click inside of focused area)

Comment: @PouyaJabbarisani You could probably use a transparent div (with dimensions set explicitly instead of by the contents) to trap any clicks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348725/can-i-make-a-div-transparent-but-clickable), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like in Ted's example.
You could use JavaScript to calculate the rectangle of the element to mask and use that info to position the overlay elements.

Here is a quick example using `jQuery`,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6aW9/1/)

An alternative is to use a html canvas with the clearRect method,

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2J5p/1/)

The caveat with the canvas solution is that the canvas is overlayed over the element so it is not possible to eg. mouse select the content in the div etc.