# Can I make a div transparent, but clickable

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, transparent

I am using a vertical slider for my whole webpage. To move between each page I want to click the top/ bottom of the page to navigate between slides. To do this I have placed a div at the top and bottom of each page and when you click that div it brings you to the next/prev slide but these divs are covering some of my content on certain pages. Is there a way to make the divs 'transparent' in colour but still available to click as a link? Sorry if I haven't explained myself properly i am new to HTML an CSS.

Comment: look for `css + opacity`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements should get you going.

Comment: If it is not working, I'd suggest using `z-index` in your styles to make sure they are on top.  Do you have code you can provide?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the duplicate is asking the opposite of this. This question is trying to receive clicks using a transparent div, the duplicate is trying to ignore them. I believe that this question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I get this problem - divs are empty by default (there's nothing in them to make transparent) so as long as you have assigned the clickable div some dimensions it should create a region you can click on where it is located on the page.

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/pWpAD/ [Top 50px pixels of the box are clickable].

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#backdiv {
    background-color: #f0f;
}

#topdiv {
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

If I've not understood your question let me know. Maybe can you provide some code?