# Making round background in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some issues to make round color inside element, to look like this

[image]

This is Bootstrap 3 code what I have for now

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 pull-left" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/logo">   
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p>Total Job Position Available <span class="badge pull-right">8</span>
        </p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I have in badge, how to make it like that and to align "Total Job Position Available"?

Comment: You use this thing called CSS

Comment: Could you create a JSfiddle example with the relevant HTML & CSS?

Comment: This is pure bootstrap 3

Answer (score 2):

First of all I dont have permission to comment.
You can use .img-circle class in a div and define css background-color and width and if needed then height as your need.

```
<div class="img-circle" style="background-color: red; width: 20px; text-align: center;">8</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a `.png` image with transparant pixels around the coloured circle. It's also possible to use a CSS trick (see also [How to make circular background using css?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8709291/1313143)).

As for the alignment, you will need to set the `vertical-align` CSS property to `middle` on `span.badge` <sub>(it *should* work like that, but `vertical-align` can give unexpected behavior imo)</sub>

Comment: No i dont want to use image