# Creating circles in CSS3

Tags: css

Evening all'

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction to create circles of text in CSS3. What are your recommended resources out there? I'm building a website for my course at Uni.

Thank you is advance.

Annique

Comment: This issue should help you : [How to draw circle in html page? - Sergey Metlov](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921792/how-to-draw-circle-in-html-page)

Comment: hot user pic....:O...:O...however check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709291/how-to-make-circular-background-using-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Circle with border](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277777/css-circle-with-border)

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .box{
   height:150px;
   width:150px; 
   background:#f1f1f1;
   border-radius:150px;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need them responsive:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="box"></div></div>
```

I've added the container `<div>` because SO posts won't accept 100% values without a fixed width container. But in you project you could use a fluid width container, or none at all.